# Software to obtain high resolution images of a STEP geometry file

Tags: image, cad, capture

When trying to obtain high resolution images of geometry files, the only option seems to take a screenshot of the software in use (Salome, Catia, etc...). Although enough in most circumstances, it seems that it is not possible to take a higher-resolution image (e.g. 3840x2160) in a standard FullHD monitor.

Is there any software or process to obtain very high resolution image (.PNG or .TIFF) of a geometry file in STEP or IGES format?

Comment: Hi, Msegade. Welcome to the site! (Sorry for the delayed feedback.) I think this question is borderline. Asking for software recommendations is off-topic (we have a site for that). But asking about a process or method more generally I think is on-topic. So it may help your question if you edit to emphasize that part (ie. if someone knows of some software, that could be part of a nice answer that goes into more detail about the technology or math equations).

Comment: Most cad software have a visualisation package attached. These can render as big image as you want. Catia almost definitely can do this. Many rendering tools can read step as is, there are even packages designed soley for this.